# How can I enable the drawing tools on my map using gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I've tried: <%= gmaps({"map_options" => @map_options,"markers" => { "data" => @markers}, "libraries" => "drawing", "circles"     => { "data" => '[
                         {"lng": -87.6355, "lat": 41.8886, "radius": 600, "strokeColor": "#FF0000"}
                         ]'
                      }}) %>

@map_options is just an instance variable where I pass a lat/lng from user's location.  everything else works fine but can't load the drawing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

- `libraries` should be in the `maps_options` hash
- it's value should be an `Array`

[Source code.](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L126)